# Regex to split text ignoring occurrences of delimiter(s) in quoted text

Tags: regex, parsing, delimiter, re2

How would I approach writing a regex where given a set of delimiters such as both `;` and `,`, I could get the following results on these examples:

```
coffee, water; tea -> [coffee, water, tea]
"coffee, black;", water; tea -> ["coffee, black;", water, tea]
```

To clarify, regular text cannot have spaces, quoted text can have spaces, delimiters inside the quotes are ignored, and all text is separated by delimiters.

I've been experimenting with regex myself, and haven't gotten the results that I want. I'm also working in an environment without lookaheads/lookbehinds. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: What implements the _split_ ? Normally split would be `\s*(?:("[^"]*")|[,;])\s*`

Comment: just to be sure: should not `black` be in the second result list?

Comment: @raul.vila dropped the ball there. Thanks.

Comment: @m0meni Can the values contain whitespace characters if they are not contained within quotes?

Comment: `\s*(?:("[^"]*")\s*[,;]|[,;])\s*`  is more accurate. In Perl, this would create an element when it is inside a capture group. Otherwise, it strips the delimiters ( here, whitespace and [,;] )

Comment: @JosephMarikle no they can't. I'll clarify that.

Comment: An actual better way is to do a custom csv parser instead of split. If you want to see that example, let me know.

Comment: You need an array of values? What language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good way `(?:\r?\n|[,;]|^)[^\S\r\n]*((?:(?:[^\S\r\n]*[^,;"\s])*(?:"[^"]*")?[^,;"\s]*))[^\S\r\n]*`

Added some WSp trim to it.
Nice demo here -> https://regex101.com/r/FsJtOE/1

Capture group 1 contains the element.
A simple find all should work.

Note, using Re2 has no assertions, but to handle all corners
it really needs them.

Unfortunately, this is as close as you can get using that regex engine.

One thing this will do is allow multiple words in non-quoted fields.

Readable version

```
 # Validate even quotes:  ^[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$   
 # Then -> 
 # ----------------------------------------------
 # Find all:  

 (?: \r? \n | [,;] | ^ )
 [^\S\r\n]* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           (?:
                [^\S\r\n]* 
                [^,;"\s] 
           )*
           (?: " [^"]* " )?
           [^,;"\s]*  
      )
 )                             # (1 end)
 [^\S\r\n]*
```

Comment: I gave the simplest solution that matches the requirement. Your answer adds a great alternative if the requirements are more complex than those in the question. But I would go with the simplest viable one to make maintenance easier.

Comment: @raul.vila - Your answer is good. Real world it's more complex.  though, especially with Re2..

Answer (score 2):

Replacing:

```
((\"[^\"]*\")|[a-zA-Z]+)[,;]
```

With:

```
$1,
```

Will give you what's inside the brackets.

Explanation:

- `((\"[^\"]*\")|[a-zA-Z]+)` any of these two options:

  - `(\"[^\"]*\")` anything between double quotes
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` any sequence of characters
- `[,;]` any occurrence of `,` or `;`

[See on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3AdZqV/2/), with this input:

```
coffee, water; tea
"coffee, black;", water; tea
```

You get this output:

```
coffee, water, tea
"coffee, black;", water, tea
```

Comment: Downvoting explanation will be welcome. I want to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what flavor of regex you're using that excludes the use of lookaheads, but would something like this work for you?

`/".*"|[^;,"\s]+/`

It checks first for a quoted value (using `".*"`) before trying values that exclude delimiters, quotes, and whitespace (using a negative character class `[^;,"\s]+`)

https://regex101.com/r/zWea28/1/

Comment: Your solution works for substitution with a little tweak: https://regex101.com/r/zWea28/2 Not sure if it can be done cleaner.

Comment: @raul.vila Nice variant.